# How to filter search result by index type in kademi?

Tags: api, search, profile, kademi

Here is my code snippet to search profile, blog, and content from kademi site using SearchManager API from search application.

```
keyword = params['q'];

var json = {
        "query": { 
            "match": {"_all":keyword}
        },

        "highlight": {
            "fields" : {
                "*" : {},
                "content" : {
                    "type" : "plain"
                }
            }
        }
    };

var indexes = ["profile", "bran-103166797", "blogs-103166797"]; // profile, content, blog
var sm = applications.search.searchManager;
var result = sm.search(JSON.stringify(json), indexes);
```

If you see my screenshot below, there are several index type for index names = profile. I just want to get data from `index type = profile` with `index name = profile`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of changes you should make
Firstly, instead of naming the indexes directly (eg bran-103166797), you should use AppIndexers so that the correct name is generated. Otherwise when you publish a new version of the website your search will still be indexing the old version:

```
        var sm = applications.search.searchManager;
        var indexers = sm.appIndexers;
        var profileIndexer = indexers.profile;
        var contentIndexer = indexers.content;
```

Then you can use the prepareSearch method on SearchManager which lets you directly manipulate the search builder:

```
        log.info("using indexers {} {}", profileIndexer, contentIndexer);
        var builder = sm.prepareSearch(profileIndexer, contentIndexer);
        builder.setSource(JSON.stringify(json));
        builder.setTypes("profile", "html");
```

Then you can execute the search query using the elasticsearch API methods. Note that in this example I'm using inline js scripts rather then a js controller, so i need to set the results in a request attribute so the template can access it.

```
        var result = builder.execute().actionGet();
        log.info("result {}", result);
        http.request.attributes.result = result;
```

Here's a full worked example:
http://docs.kademi.co/howtos/devs/advanced-search-pages-with-the-searchmanager-api.html

And the source of the template in that example is here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>search page</title>
</head>
<body>
    #script()
    <script>
        var keyword = http.request.params.q;

        var json = {
                "query": { 
                    "match": {"_all":keyword}
                },
                "fields" : ["nickName", "title"],
                "highlight": {
                    "fields" : {
                        "*" : {},
                        "content" : {
                            "type" : "plain"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

        var sm = applications.search.searchManager;
        var indexers = sm.appIndexers;
        var profileIndexer = indexers.profile;
        var contentIndexer = indexers.content;
        log.info("using indexers {} {}", profileIndexer, contentIndexer);
        var builder = sm.prepareSearch(profileIndexer, contentIndexer);
        builder.setSource(JSON.stringify(json));
        builder.setTypes("profile", "html");
        var result = builder.execute().actionGet();
        log.info("result {}", result);
        http.request.attributes.result = result; // make available to templating
    </script>
    #end

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Search</h1>            
        <p class="pull-right lead">Showing $request.attributes.result.hits.hits.size() of $request.attributes.result.hits.totalHits hits</p>
        <table class="table table-striped">
        #foreach( $hit in  $request.attributes.result.hits)
        <tr>
            <td>
                $!hit.fields.nickName.value $!hit.fields.title.value
            </td>
            <td>$hit.type</td>
        </tr>
        #end
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- for debugging, just display the search result as json -->
    <pre>$request.attributes.result</pre>                
</body>
```

Comment: I didnt say explicitly, but the method above allows setting the document types to match on